# Request for a 成语 to describe a person with all of 貌, 才, and 德

Tags: chengyu

We can use 才貌双全 to describe a person with both 貌 and 才 and 德才兼备 to describe a person with both 才 and 德.

Does there exist a 成语 that describes a person with all of the three?

Comment: I am almost sure there is no 成语 that explicitly covers all these three qualities. You can always make up phrases for that purpose, but it requires high language proficiency to do it right.

Comment: This is one Specifically for women: [德容言功](http://www.zdic.net/c/7/77/121396.htm#cy) or [德言工貌](http://www.zdic.net/c/7/70/111423.htm#cy) or [德言工容](http://www.zdic.net/c/7/77/121364.htm#cy) or [德言容功](http://www.zdic.net/c/7/77/121365.htm#cy). 德=品德, 容/貌=容貌, 工/功=女红(needlework, in the old times, it's the 才 for women).

Comment: @Stan, nice point, but those words are just used to describe female

Comment: @shuangwhywhy I've mentioned it in that comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think there is an idiom describing all of the three.

In Chinese, it is very common to use parallelisms, such as "他才貌兼具，德艺双馨".
I used little different terms from yours and parallelize them together to avoid literal duplication.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In the olden times, for females 女子无才便是德 and for males 貌 is not important at all. 德言工貌 is too localized.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow in ancient times, appearance was very important even for men; it was considered a sign of virtue.

Answer (score -2):

As a chinesse girl, if we meet a man with three of those at this time, we call him as 男神（just like 女神goddes,who are perfect）.

---

**there is 才貌耀德 you can use it in writing, but don't use in oral Chinese.**

Comment: 男神 and 女神 are internet slang, which doesn't seem like what the OP is looking for.

Comment: 才貌耀德? Is that a 成语? Google produces 0 result.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow never heard it before either.